# Spark streaming - array of objects processing

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark, streaming

In Apache Spark I need to process one column containing array of objects. From each object I need to extract fields stayBegin and stayEnd, put them into concatenated one field and calculate the duration as difference between those fields.

Sample source data:

```
"serviceDetails": [
    {
        "serviceType": " xwFOisGAJbJlgpgodye",
        "serviceOrder": 20686918,
        "stayOrder": 14938272,
        "stayBegin": "2023-04-19T10:39:43",
        "stayEnd": "2023-04-19T11:39:43",
        "locationID": "NXPlsqagPcYMTPwJqErX"
    },
    {
        "serviceType": "wQmJTXOhzBAwbaatftsZ",
        "serviceOrder": 2949213,
        "stayOrder": 11157169,
        "stayBegin": "2023-04-19T10:39:43",
        "stayEnd": "2023-04-19T11:39:43",
        "locationID": "cJxXElbuuRVNMERFykpO"
    }
]
```

Desired output from processing:

```
"serviceDetails": [
    {
        "stayPeriod": "2023-04-19T10:39:43 - 2023-04-19T11:39:43",
        "stayDuration": 3600
    },
    {
        "stayPeriod": "2023-04-19T10:39:43 - 2023-04-19T11:39:43",
        "stayDuration": 3600
    }
]
```

Can anybody help how to deal with that?

I expect output as described above.

PS. I use Scala and Apache Streaming.

Comment: do you have any code that is not working? some error message? The article [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) could help you to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

Using transform is the easy and efficient way.

```
transform(flatten(col("serviceDetails")), (col: Column) => concat(date_format(col.getField("stayBegin"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"), lit(" - "), date_format(col.getField("stayEnd"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")))
```